# Why my disk not in /dev/diskstats

Tags: linux, df

I can see the device `/dev/xsda` by `df -h` command.

But the device not shown in `/proc/diskstats`. Instead, there are devices names as below:

```
sda
sda0
....
sda6
```

lsbk does not show the device either

```
    $lsblk -a
    NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda            8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
    ├─sda1         8:1    0     3M  0 part
    ├─sda2         8:2    0     1G  0 part
    ├─sda3         8:3    0    50G  0 part
    ├─sda4         8:4    0     2G  0 part
    ├─sda5         8:5    0  97.7G  0 part
    └─sda6         8:6    0  72.9G  0 part
    nvme10n1     259:15   0     7T  0 disk
    nvme11n1     259:9    0     7T  0 disk
    loop0          7:0    0   100G  0 loop
    loop1          7:1    0   100G  0 loop
    loop2          7:2    0   100G  0 loop
    loop3          7:3    0   100G  0 loop
    loop4          7:4    0   100G  0 loop
    loop5          7:5    0   100G  0 loop
    nvme0n1      259:1    0     7T  0 disk
    ├─nvme0n1p1  259:2    0     4K  0 part
    ├─nvme0n1p5  259:3    0   100G  0 part
    ├─nvme0n1p6  259:4    0   100G  0 part
    ├─nvme0n1p7  259:5    0   100G  0 part
    ├─nvme0n1p8  259:6    0   100G  0 part /some_mnt
    ├─nvme0n1p9  259:7    0   100G  0 part
    └─nvme0n1p10 259:8    0   100G  0 part
    nvme1n1      259:12   0     7T  0 disk /etc/hosts
```

ls of `/dev/xsda` output as below

```
$ls -ld /dev/xsda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 6 Apr 26 14:51 /dev/xsda
```

So questions are:

- What is `/dev/xsda`?
- Why it does not shown in `/proc/diskstats`?
- What does the x means in `/dev/xsda`?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/xsda`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `lsblk` to get detailed information about block devices `lsblk -a`? Weird to not see it in `proc/diskstats`.

Comment: Hi@Kamil Maciorowski I added the corresponding info in the post

Comment: Hi @Romain I added the  `lsblk` in post

Comment: The very first `b` and `259, 6` in the output of `ls -l` are important. In the output of `lsblk` `259:6` makes me believe `nvme0n1p8` and `xsda` are two names for *the same device*. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124233/108618) where it states "there's nothing to stop you creating multiple devices nodes (files) that refer to the same device". If `nvme0n1p8` appears in `/proc/diskstats` (well, does it?), then this is probably the reason `xsda` does not appear. Now the question may be: why are there two nodes for the same device? It's a slightly different question.